# If there is a value in another cell - take that value instead

Tags: google-sheets

I don't know how to properly phrase that. Let's say I have something like this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngktO.png).

What formula will result in following equation: 4 + 2 + 7 + 2 + 7 ?

I basically want SUM that picks value from the same row in different column every time there is any value instead of the value in originally targeted column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general technique for things like this is to create another column that contains a formula that calculates the values that you want, and then sum that column.

I'll assume that your first column is A and your second column is B, and the top row is row 1. Go to an unused column (I'll use C). In this column, put this formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B1), A1, B1)
```

Meaning, if the B column is blank, this cell should be the same as what's in the A column, and if it isn't, it should be the same as what's in the B column.

Copy the formula down for all the rows you want to sum. Then, at the bottom of row A (In your example case, in A6) sum the column with the formula:

```
=SUM(C1:C5)
```

You can hide the column with the formula if you don't want it to show.

Answer (score 0):

In a separate column, copied down and then summed:

```
=if(count(A1:B1)=1,A1,B1)
```

Comment: `count` works too, unless there are blank values in the A column.